# How can a Content-Disposition filename be matched using a regex?

Tags: regex, perl, email, spam-prevention

How can a Content-Disposition filename be matched using a regex ?
I need to enter a regex in an antispam software which should match the following

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 "filename"=attached.bat
```

where *attached* could be any filename word.

Also this should not be matched

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
other text here
 "filename"=attached.bat
```

I would match (and block) using a regex all email having the text above.
Is it possible using a single regex row ?

note : I found a way to match "Content-Disposition: attachment;" OR "filename"=attached.bat" using 2 separate regex, but I would match "Content-Disposition: attachment;" AND "filename"=attached.bat" using a single regex. Is it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: I tried this
/(Content)(-)(Disposition)(:)( )(attachment)(;)+"[\s\S]*"+(")(filename)(")(=)(attached)(\.)(bat)/g

but it does now work 

this is my regex1
  /(Content)(-)(Disposition)(:)( )(attachment)(;)/g
  
  this is my regex2
  /(")(filename)(")(=)(attached)(\.)(bat)/g

Comment: no sorry if it was not specified, it's perl

Comment: Please update your question with these regexes you tried, explain what does not work, and how you want them to work.

Comment: I updated with an example which should not be matched, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Content-Disposition: attachment;\s*"filename"=[-+.\w]+`.

http://www.regexr.com/3d4p4